# SQL Dynamic Pivot for Some Columns

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I'm trying to create a dynamic pivot code, where some columns are pivoted while others are not. Currently, I have one row per parent-child combination. I want a table where it is one row for every parent, with columns for child1, child2, etc. Some parents have multiple children, so number of columns(children) per parent is dynamic. I already have a column ordering the children by birthdate, and I'm adding this "childnumber" to the child columns.

Here's the sample table I'm starting with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/990f6/2

```
+===============+===========+-=============+=============+================+=============+==============+
|    parent     | parentage | parentgender |  childname  | childbirthdate | childgender | childnumber  |
+===============+===========+==============+=============+================+=============+==============+
| John Smith    |        32 | M            | Jane Smith  | 2005-05-21     | F           |            1 |
| John Smith    |        32 | M            | Billy Smith | 2010-01-01     | M           |            2 |
| Katherine Doe |        40 | F            | Drew Fine   | 2015-08-09     | M           |            1 |
| Paula Lee     |        28 | F            | Peter Lee   | 2009-12-30     | M           |            1 |
| Paula Lee     |        28 | F            | Tim Lee     | 2013-10-15     | M           |            2 |
| Paula Lee     |        28 | F            | Andrew Lee  | 2014-06-27     | M           |            3 |
+---------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

The final result should be:

```
+===============+===========+==============+============+=================+==============+=============+=================+==============+============+=================+===============+
|    parent     | parentage | parentgender | childname1 | childbirthdate1 | childgender1 | childname2  | childbirthdate2 | childgender2 | childname3 | childbirthdate3 | childgender3  |
+===============+===========+==============+============+=================+==============+=============+=================+==============+============+=================+===============+
| John Smith    |        32 | M            | Jane Smith | 2005-05-21      | F            | Billy Smith | 2010-01-01      | M            | null       | null            | null          |
| Katherine Doe |        40 | F            | Drew Fine  | 2015-08-09      | M            | null        | null            | null         | null       | null            | null          |
| Paula Lee     |        28 | F            | Peter Lee  | 2009-12-30      | M            | Tim Lee     | 2013-10-15      | M            | Andrew Lee | 2014-06-27      | M             |
+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

My SQL Server Code Attempt:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('finaltable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE finaltable

DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(col + '_' + CAST(childnumber as varchar(50)))
FROM
  families
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT parent, ' + @columns + '  
             FROM (
                SELECT parent, parentage, parentgender, num = col+''_''+ CAST(childnumber as varchar(50)) 
                FROM (
                    SELECT parent, childnumber, childname, childbirthdate, childgender
                    FROM families
                    ) AS x
            ) AS source
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(childnumber)
                FOR num in (' + @columns + ')
            ) AS pvt '

execute(@query);
```

I can't get this query to execute, and I'm not sure if my issue is with defining 'col' or if there are additional problems such as needing to unpivot first. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So have you used `print(@query)` to inspect the query created and see whats incorrect about the query?

Comment: Is this SQL server or MySQL? The fiddle you have provided in for MySQL

Comment: You have a non trivial requirement. You have multiple problems in your query (undefined `col` being the most obvious) . As a general approach I suggest you try to get static query working first and then convert it to dynamic query. Try to get static query working for two children only at first and once you have all of the information you need showing then you can make an attempt at "dynamising" it.

Comment: Useful link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192524/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for the useful link and asking about the fiddle. It's my first time using it so was unfamiliar. I've updated the fiddle to show that it's for SQL server.